# How to create a one to one singleton relation

Tags: java, singleton, one-to-one

I've got two singleton in my application and here is my problem:
Each one of them need each other so i can't build any of the two because i'll get a stackOverflowError. How to get over it ?

```
public class ApplicationService {

    private ApplicationDao applicationDao;
    private DerogationService derogationService;
    private LogService logService;
    private static ApplicationService applicationServiceInstance;

    private ApplicationService() 
    {
        applicationDao = ApplicationDao.getInstance();
        derogationService = DerogationService.getInstance();
        logService = LogService.getInstance();
    }

    public static synchronized ApplicationService getInstance(){
        if(applicationServiceInstance == null)
        {
            applicationServiceInstance = new ApplicationService();
        }
        return applicationServiceInstance;
    }
```

.

```
public class DerogationService {

    private DerogationDao derogationDao;
    private ApplicationService applicationService;
    private DroitService droitService;
    private static DerogationService derogationServiceInstance;

    private DerogationService(){

        applicationService = ApplicationService.getInstance();
        droitService =  DroitService.getInstance();
        derogationDao = DerogationDao.getInstance();
    }

    public static synchronized DerogationService getInstance(){
        if(derogationServiceInstance == null)
        {
            derogationServiceInstance = new DerogationService();
        }
        return derogationServiceInstance;
    }
```

Thx guys ! :)

Comment: How about just calling `<other class>.getInstance()` when you need the instance of the other class, instead of storing it in a field?

Comment: Because i call the method very often and i think the code would be less readable this way. 
I'm pretty sure it must be a way to do it that way

Comment: You can add a `null` check in each constructor to only call `getInstance()` if the reference to the other singletone is `null`.

Comment: @Titus no - because the other constructor is invoked before the assignment of the instance field. It's *always* null currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found how to do it.

```
public class ApplicationService {

    private ApplicationDao applicationDao;
    private DerogationService derogationService;
    private LogService logService;
    private static ApplicationService applicationServiceInstance;

    private ApplicationService() 
    {
        applicationDao = ApplicationDao.getInstance();
        //I don't do it there 
        //derogationService = DerogationService.getInstance();
        logService = LogService.getInstance();
    }

    public static synchronized ApplicationService getInstance(){
        if(applicationServiceInstance == null)
        {
            applicationServiceInstance = new ApplicationService();
            // But here, so i won't get this loop problem.
            applicationServiceInstance.derogationService = DerogationService.getInstance();
        }
        return applicationServiceInstance;
    }
```

Thx for the guy who gave me an idea start even if he delete his post just after.. 
And thx for all the answers

Answer (score 0):

As you state in your OP without actually saying it you have a cyclic reference problem.

You could consider using the Spring container (amongst others) to resolve this.